# Java Service Bus Shared Access Token

Tags: java, azure, azureservicebus

```
Configuration config =
                ServiceBusConfiguration.configureWithSASAuthentication(
                        URL,
                        "RootManageSharedAccessKey",
                        token,
                        ".servicebus.windows.net"
                );
```

This is the code for configuration for java service bus implementation.  I am interested in passing a shared access signature not a shared access key. I am not sure if this implementation for the java azure sdk supports this. How exactly would I do this.  I keep getting a 401-unauthorized error when I use the shared access signature token in the token variable.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/services/azure-servicebus/src/main/java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/services/servicebus/ServiceBusConfiguration.java#L224) of Azure Service Bus SDK for Java, the four arguments for the function `configureWithSASAuthentication` should be the `namespace`, `sasKeyName`, `sasKey` & `serviceBusRootUri`(default pass ".servicebus.windows.net").

The `namespace`, `sasKeyName` & `sasKey` you can find them via click the `CONNECTION INFORMATION` button at the bottom of your service bus, please see the figures below.

Fig 1. The `CONNECTION INFORMATION` button at the bottom of the service bus page
[image]

Fig 2. Copy the `CONNECTION STRING` and extract the namespace, sasKeyName & sasKey
[image]

For example, the connection string is `Endpoint=sb://abc-ns.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=ABCdefg123!@#=`, then the `namespace`, `sasKeyName`, `sasKey` are separately `abc-ns`, `RootManageSharedAccessKey`, `ABCdefg123!@#=`.

So the code should be as below.

```
Configuration config =
                ServiceBusConfiguration.configureWithSASAuthentication(
                        "abc-ns",
                        "RootManageSharedAccessKey",
                        "ABCdefg123!@#=",
                        ".servicebus.windows.net"
                );
```

And you can also find them at the `CONFIGURE` tab of your service bus page, please see the figure below.

Fig 3. The `CONFIGURE` tab
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you created a Configuration object here. Normally we use it to creat a topic in Java, eg:

```
Configuration config =
    ServiceBusConfiguration.configureWithSASAuthentication(
      "namespace",
      "sasKeyName",
      "sasKey",
      "serviceBusRootUri"
      );

ServiceBusContract service = ServiceBusService.create(config);
TopicInfo topicInfo = new TopicInfo("TestTopic");
CreateTopicResult result = service.createTopic(topicInfo);
```

or to create a queue, eg:

```
  Configuration config =
        ServiceBusConfiguration.configureWithSASAuthentication(
                "namespace",
                "sasKeyName",
                "sasKey",
                "serviceBusRootUri"
                );

ServiceBusContract service = ServiceBusService.create(config);
QueueInfo queueInfo = new QueueInfo("TestQueue");
CreateQueueResult result = service.createQueue(queueInfo);
```

and also we can create them by shared access signature:
create a topic(c#)

```
Uri uri = ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("sb", "namespace", string.Empty);
string name = "sasKeyName";
string key = "sasKey";

TokenProvider tokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider(name, key);

NamespaceManager namespaceManager = new NamespaceManager(uri, tokenProvider);
namespaceManager.CreateTopic("DataCollectionTopic");
```

create a queue(c#):

```
Uri uri = ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("sb", 
                "namespace", string.Empty);
string name = "sasKeyName";
string key = "sasKey";

TokenProvider tokenProvider = 
    TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider(name, key);
NamespaceManager namespaceManager = 
    new NamespaceManager(uri, tokenProvider);
namespaceManager.CreateQueue("DataCollectionQueue");
```

The namespace, sasKeyName, sasKey are configured in portal just as what Perter showed.